# Ubuntu 23.10 released?

Tags: release-management, 23.10

I have a simple question, has Ubuntu 23.10 been released? Why I ask is when I query the release information, it comes back negative:

```
david@david-XPS-15-9530:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
[sudo] password for david: 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found.
```

Also in the `Software & Updates` app, I have `Any new version` marked for any new releases, and no notification has been given.

Comment: The upgrade from 23.04 to 23.10 is not yet opened due to an open issue for the update. If you're brave, you can issue `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` to upgrade. For me it worked fine, although during the update I had some weird fonts. After final reboot, all was fine.

Comment: Check here for status: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/mantic-minotaur-23-10-release-status-tracking/37887

Comment: Read the status page if you want to find out - https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/mantic-minotaur-23-10-release-status-tracking/37887 - it reports the release is still **IN PROGRESS** and will change to RELEASED once the full release progress has completed.   Release is currently open for new installs (*or for those who want to force upgrade as per instructions (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManticUpgrades) but see my prior answer for more details*)

Comment: I appreciated the information, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what version of Ubuntu you are trying to upgrade FROM you may have no upgrade target when running `do-release-upgrade`. For example, my installation of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS cannot upgrade to 23.10 because 23.10 is not a valid target for my Ubuntu installation.

Running `sudo do-release-upgrade` Ubuntu 22.04 the default settings output

> There is no development version of an LTS available. To upgrade to the
> latest non-LTS development release set Prompt=normal in
> /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.

If you open `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` it is probable that you are set to `Prompt=lts` which will not allow you to go to 23.10 because 23.10 is not a LTS release.

You can however try setting `Prompt=normal` and it will look for the next release that is a valid release and allow you to update to that target.

Comment: While this is generally correct, `mantic` will not show due to an open blocker even if you currently run 23.04. See [here](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/mantic-minotaur-23-10-release-status-tracking/37887)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Hey just checking is this release available now? I'm currently on 22.04 LTS, will I need to upgrade to 23.04 then 23.10? or a direct upgrade will be available in some time.